Binomial test for finding ratios
I have tried reading about the concept here:
https://www.ncl.ac.uk/webtemplate/ask-assets/external/maths-resources/statistics/hypothesis-testing/hypothesis-testing-with-the-binomial-distribution.html
but I am not sure how exactly to implement it and which variables to use where. Since I have 3 different variables: gender, job type, and tool.

Since all the pairs add up to $100$, these are presumably percentages.  It would be better to use counts.  You also need a hypothesis to test: if the question is whether different companies or different departments are distributed differently the answer is yes as you can see the percentages are different, but if you are asking about how extreme the different distributions are assuming that females and males are allocated at random then you need to think about what should count as extreme.

Are you looking to do a binomial test within companies (i.e. finding if the rates of female to male are 50 50) or between companies (to find if the rates of male or female are the same at companies A and B or C)

If you have the counts, please edit the Q to add them!

Um, that complicates things. If these are a sample representative (hopefully??) of a larger but finite population...

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binomtest.html

"Or should I skip the departments and do a general ratio comparison between different companies?" I guess that your teacher is a bit mean and wants you to think of a sensible comparison. This is very tricky as a question on stack exchange, if there is no point behind the test, except for 'the teacher asks for it', then it is not easy for outsiders to say how exactly is the best way to perform the test (and which test to perform). Do you want to skip departments or not, how should we know?

@x89 The page that Roger V. mentions has a section "examples" that should be easily transposable to your case. If you don't see how, you should explain where you are stuck exactly. Also, if you haven't read it, there are some recommendations to follow relative to homework questions: https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

@x89 but you don't have the numbers for the average of the companies. You could average or sum the numbers for the different departments, but that makes little sense if those departments have different sizes. It is unclear what this data is and why you analyse it, that makes it difficult to tell how you should perform your test. Is it a textbook exercise?

Please edit to describe what your data represent & how they were collected; clearly formulate your research question, & explain your difficulty in applying statistical reasoning to answer it.

With your data, the differences are such large, that you won't have to worry much about details. You can perform nine individual tests and if you like correct it for multiple comparisons.

Are those your real data? You got exactly a multiple of 5 or 10 every in seven out of nine cases?

If you would skip to bother yourself with statistical details and testing, what would you conclude from this data? What values are remarkable? If you express your results first in simplistic language, then you may get more easily to what it is that you measured and that you want to expose to a statistical test. --- So instead of puzzling and worrying about some test that seems abstract to you and you can not yet handle very comfortably, try to analyse and discuss the results with your common sense without mathematics (following that use mathematics to make the common sense quantifiable).

The statistical tests should follow what you want to measure with your experiment, not the other way around.

trying to show that certain tools have bias so there are more women images generated when generating for certain professions like housekeepers. Nine individual tests, how? If it were upto I would not do any statistical test at all - as the visualizations alone are enough. But its an academic requirement so.. @SextusEmpiricus

I address here only the "pythonic" part for carrying a test for a pair of values. Note however, that if the python implementation is indeed the main issue here, the question is more appropriate for the Stackexchange rather than the statistics community. Or perhaps it has to be split into parts which are properly programming and those which are statistics.
Here is an example of carrying the test for any pair of values in the table above:
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

from __future__ import division #importing non-integer division
import numpy as np #importing basic python math library
from scipy.stats import binomtest #importing binomial test

#first example
k = 98; n=100
res = binomtest(k, n, p=0.5, alternative='two-sided')
print(res.pvalue)

#second example
k=10; n=100
res = binomtest(k, n, p=0.5, alternative='two-sided')
print(res.pvalue)

p=0.5, alternative='two-sided' are default values, so they need not necessarily be explicitly spelled here (p=0.5 reflects our null hypothesis that the gender ratio is 50/50). One could also import all the data table as, e.g., a pandas dataframe and loop over it to test all the pairs. res object contains the final statistic, p-value, etc.
There are also similar statistical functions for carrying other tests, including chi-squared - e.g., this one (this is not necessarily what you have to use, as there are many chi-squared capacities in scipy, which can be found by searching in scipy web-page or simply googling.)
